# LLDB - Evaluate Address In Register

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, lldb

To view my stack in LLDB, I currently use the following:

```
(lldb) register read rbp --format hex
rbp = 0x00007fff5fbff820
```

Then to view the first 64-bytes growing down:

```
(lldb) memory read --size 4 --format x --count 16 `0x00007fff5fbff820-64`
0x7fff5fbff7e0: 0x5fbff900 0x00007fff 0x00000000 0x00000000
0x7fff5fbff7f0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
0x7fff5fbff800: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
0x7fff5fbff810: 0x5fbff838 0x00000006 0x00000008 0x00000000
```

I haven't been able to find how to do it, but is there any way to replace the expression:

```
`0x00007fff5fbff820-64`
```

With something more like:

```
`%rbp-64`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$rbp-64`

There are also shortcut formatters for memory read and print that act like gdb.  e.g.

x/16x `$rbp`

see "help gdb-format" for details on accepted formatter chars for x/ and p/.  These are really just command aliases to memory read -G and expr -G.